# Regex. Check string is in these characters always true

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I've searched quite a bit but can't work out why my regex is always returning true.

I need to validate that a whole string contains only numbers, letters, spaces - and _

I have the `^` and `$` to match from the start to the end and the `+` so it's at least one character.

But it always returns true when I test it with `#[]<>/.,` and so on.

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 -_]+$");
    return rg.IsMatch(strToCheck);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `-` symbol present at the middle of the character class. `-` in the middle acts as a range operator. ie, it allows all characters which falls within the range  from space to `_` . To avoid `-` acts as a range operator, you need to put the `-` symbol at the first or at the last inside the character class or escape it.

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+$"
```

OR

```
@"^[-a-zA-Z0-9 _]+$
```

Comment: should it be delimited?

Comment: You could also keep it in the middle if you escape it. `\-`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the hyphen since it is at that position inside of the character class.

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9 \-_]+$");
```

**Note:** Inside of a character class the hyphen has **special** meaning. You can place it as the first or last character of the class. In some regex implementations, you can also place directly after a range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to precede it with a backslash in order to add it to your character class.